# How to pass binary key to openssl

Tags: openssl, hmac, gdax-api

I'm stumped trying to pass the key parameter to `openssl dgst`. I'm trying to interface to the GDAX trading platform and each request must be signed by HMAC. They clearly say to

> "first base64-decode the alphanumeric secret string (resulting in 64
>   bytes) before using it as the key for HMAC."

This results in a 64-byte binary string. But the openssl command line program simply says `-hmac key` meaning that you supply the key as a parameter on the command line, which is fine if it is simple ASCII. But I see no way to supply a binary string of bytes as the key. Is there a way to do this?

(also any general advice about directing GDAX with `curl` is welcome too)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can specify a binary key in hex format like this:

```
$ openssl dgst -mac hmac -macopt hexkey:0102030405 myfile
```