# Openssl | dgst -sha256 -hmac different signatures than online and in java

Tags: bash, openssl, sha256, hmac

I have been trying to figure out why the command in bash is generating a different signature than online converters as well as my java code.

Online and in Java it a value="value" and a key="key" generates the following sha256 signature in hex: 
90fbfcf15e74a36b89dbdb2a721d9aecffdfdddc5c83e27f7592594f71932481

[image]

OR

[image]
This is across the board from online tools to my java code.

Yet in bash it produces the following output:

[image]

Does anyone know what would cause this difference? And which one is incorrect or is it printing in a different format?

[Online Converter 1](https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html) OR [Online Converter 2](https://hash.online-convert.com/sha256-generator)

Comment: Add your bash and openssl version. I cannot reproduce the problem with openssl version 1.0.2g.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I have same issue with Node.JS, C++/Qt which are producing same hash and different in command line:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/50884630/630169 Have You solved Your issue?

Comment: I'm getting: builtin echo -n "value" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "key"
(stdin)= 90fbfcf15e74a36b89dbdb2a721d9aecffdfdddc5c83e27f7592594f71932481
with OpenSSL 1.1.0g, bash 4.4.19(1)-release.

Comment: This other question may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47766278/how-to-pass-binary-key-to-openssl