# Node.JS crypto.createHmac('sha256') command line analog

Tags: node.js, linux, command-line, sha256, cryptojs

In Node.js I use following code

```
hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', SECRET).update(file).digest('hex');
```

to calculate HMAC. However Linux command line analog produces different hash code:

```
> openssl sha256 -hmac "SECRET" file
```

What is wrong in command line? What are correct arguments?

Comment: Can I ask you about ``file``?

Comment: For example, it supposes that the sample is ``var hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', 'SECRET').update('file').digest('hex');``, you can retrieve the same result by ``echo -n "file" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "SECRET"``.

Comment: @Tanaike `file` - just some data variable, byte array, file content. For command line correct analog will be: `cat filename | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "SECRET"` - same as `> openssl sha256 -hmac "SECRET" filename` but result is wrong, different. Which is strange as `crypto` uses `openssl`.

Comment: I think that if the file is a text file, the result is the same, and if the file is a binary file, the result is difference. Can I ask you about the method for reading ``file`` at node.js?

Comment: @Tanaike, file is text JSON. In node I get its content via HTTP. File content is correct as I have same hash in C++/Qt for it - `QByteArray hash = QMessageAuthenticationCode::hash(fileContent, SECRET, QCryptographicHash::Sha256).toHex();` The problem somewhere in `openssl` command line arguments.

Comment: Thank you for your additional information.